# How do I adjust the server path for my working copy in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, commit

I have had a repository with the following layout:

```
//server/wrongname/superfluousdir/trunk/...
```

Now I have moved `trunk` to the root of the repository (using the TortoiseSVN repo browser) and changed the repository name (using SVNManager):

```
//server/correctname/trunk/...
```

I have a working copy folder which contains everything in `trunk`. It has several changed files. I told TortoiseSVN to use the new repository name with the `Relocate...` command.

However, if I try to do a commit now, it will still commit to

```
//server/correctname/superfluousdir/trunk/...
```

How do I correct the path to which it should commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm more used to doing this with the command-line, but it sounds like you got the relocate wrong. The command line syntax would be

```
svn switch --relocate //server/wrongname/superfluousdir/ //server/correctname/
```

i.e. from-path, to-path. I guess Tortoise got the two mixed up and really did

```
svn switch --relocate //server/wrongname/ //server/correctname/
```

i.e. with the wrong from path.

I think at this point you should try the switch option: that should give you //server/correctname/superfluousdir/trunk/ which you can edit to the correct path.